# How do you display the result from a UNION ALL query as links?

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink, union-all

I am having problems with echoing the result from a sql query as links when using UNION ALL.

The tables looks like this:

> TABLE: posts
> id username date comment
>
> TABLE: files
> id username date file

The "file" row contains urls to uploaded files.

The code i have for displaying the results:

```
<?php
$sql="SELECT * FROM posts 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM files 
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 100";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<div> <?php echo $rows['comment']; ?> </div>
<div> <a href="<?php echo $rows['file']; ?>"><?php echo $rows['file']; ?></a> </div>

<?php
}
?>
```

Now everything sorts out in the right order, but the filenames wont be displayed as links, only plain text.
There are no problems, echoing out the links if i run a query on the files table only.

I guess the big question is: How do you display the result from a UNION ALL query as links?

Comment: What is your output? Looks like everything is fine from that code.

Comment: The query might be the problem. Try to use a join instead of a union

Comment: My output is more or less as it should, its just that the filenames arent displayed as links, only plain text, even though ive used the html a tag.

Comment: I have tried join too, but the whole page turned blank on me when i used it :) I will look into it, ibu.

Comment: @Lassa :Are you able to click om file name and open it?

Comment: @Lassa: As long as you don't provide the needed info, it is impossible to determine the cause. The output (html code) you get in the browser would help.

Comment: paste here what is in view source in anchor tag

Comment: <div>filename.gif</div>
<a href=""></a>

This is the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you perform a UNION query, columns are combined meaning your `comment` and `file` columns will be the same, the resultset name of which will be `comment` (the first select statement). See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

I'd be more inclined to use two separate queries, one against the `posts` table and the second against `files`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have in posts table

```
1  2012-03-26 "a comment"
2  2012-03-26 "another comment"
```

and in files table:

```
1  2012-03-26 "./myfile/txt"
2  2012-03-26 "./ico.gif"
```

The union all will be:

```
ID Date       Comment/file
1  2012-03-26 "a comment"
1  2012-03-26 "./myfile/txt"
2  2012-03-26 "another comment"
2  2012-03-26 "./ico.gif"
```

(The order is not garanted)

So if you try to prind for each row a div with the comment and a div with the file as link this won't work. In you case it seems to only display the comment div (because the query result row name must be comment)

However if what you want to achieve can be done using a join like stated above.
It can be this, if for a posts id match a file row with the same id

```
SELECT p.comment comment f.file file FROM posts p
INNER JOIN files f ON f.id = p.id
```

the result will be:

```
 comment          file
"a comment"       "./myfile/txt"
"another comment" "ico.gif"
```

Regards